# How to unsmooth polygons in 3dsMax

Tags: 3dsmax, low-poly

i am creating a game using a "Low Poly Art Style".   Meaning there is an effect of polygons on the model.  Whilst modelling a tree, a portion somehow became smooth and i continued to model not knowing this.  What i am wondering is,  is there a way to unsmooth these polygons to look similar to the rest of the model.  EDIT... The smoothed are is on the tree trunk in the middle.

Below is an image of the model in question.
[image: Low Poly Tree]

Thanks is advance guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In face sub-object mode, select all your faces and then scroll down the inspector to the ["Polygon: Smoothing Groups" section and click "Clear All"](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/cg/uploads/2014/01/3dsMax_Fire_Extinguisher_PT2_34.jpg)

(Can't embed the image from my current network, but it's step 2 from [this tutorial](http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-game-ready-fire-extinguisher-with-3d-studio-max-part-2--cg-31654))

Comment: Brilliant man thanks very much your a lifesaver :D